# Apache Kafka - migrating physical broker nodes to RHEL OS

Tags: apache-kafka, operating-system, migration, coexistence

I am working on a problem to migrate the physical hosts on which Apache Kafka cluster is running -from CentOSv7 to RHEL v9 . Each node has one disk for the OS and 1 or more data disks (different brokers) for the actual (kafka stored) data.  I plan to move one or more nodes at a time (for a rack) "with" the data disk as is, so I do not have to do the data movement on OS upgrade, does anyone know if -

1. The Kafka broker nodes can co-exist and work well with brokers on different OS ?
2. Migrating to the new OS with the same data disks could pose any issues when the node is started and added back to the cluster and join the cluster without any read/write issues from/to the existing disks.  If someone has experience doing a similar thing in the past, please share.
3. Also planning to upgrade the kafka version from 3.2 to 3.3 at the same time.
   Since , it's a kafka minor version upgrade, again I do not anticipate any issues, but any inputs here will help.
   Here is the official doc I am planning to follow, https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_3_3_1